# log4j log message during log4j initialization

Tags: log4j

I was trying to setup log4j (xml based) configuration, [Use LevelRangeFilter](http://wiki.apache.org/logging-log4j/LogToAppenderByLevel), as described in the official site. Everything is fine so far, except log4j spit out its own log messages till it initializes. After the ***'finished configuration'*** line, everything is normal. Also, there is an error stating ***"log4j: Could not find root logger information. Is this OK?"*** .

thanks.

```
log4j: reset attribute= "false".
log4j: Threshold ="null".
log4j: Level value for root is  [all].
log4j: root level set to ALL
log4j: Class name: [org.apache.log4j.FileAppender]
log4j: Setting property [file] to [logs/debug.log].
log4j: Parsing layout of class: "org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout"
log4j: Setting property [conversionPattern] to [[%d{ISO8601}] %-5p %c %m %n].
log4j: Setting property [levelMax] to [DEBUG].
log4j: Setting property [levelMin] to [DEBUG].
log4j: Setting property [acceptOnMatch] to [true].
log4j: Adding filter of type [class org.apache.log4j.varia.LevelRangeFilter] to appender named [debug-out].
log4j: setFile called: logs/debug.log, true
log4j: setFile ended
..................
...................
log4j: Adding appender named [error-out] to category [root].
log4j: Class name: [org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender]
log4j: Setting property [target] to [System.err].
log4j: Parsing layout of class: "org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout"
log4j: Setting property [conversionPattern] to [[%d{ISO8601}] %-5p %c %m %n].
log4j: Setting property [levelMin] to [INFO].
log4j: Setting property [levelMax] to [FATAL].
log4j: Adding filter of type [class org.apache.log4j.varia.LevelRangeFilter] to appender named [console].
log4j: Adding appender named [console] to category [root].
log4j: Reading configuration from URL file:/C:/Work/test/conf/log4j.xml
log4j: Could not find root logger information. Is this OK?
log4j: Finished configuring.
```

Comment: Already solved the problem? Your link is not available anymore, so can you please extend your question with your xml-configuration? At least the part of the Root-Logger-definition? its just like this:
<root> 
    <level value ="TRACE" /> 

    <appender-ref ref="StandardConsole" /> 
 <appender-ref ref="ErrorAppender"/>
 <appender-ref ref="EmailAppender"/>
 </root>

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In the XML configuration `log4j.xml`:

```
<log4j:configuration debug="true" xmlns:log4j='http://jakarta.apache.org/log4j/'>
```

set the `debug` attribute to `false`.

Happy logging :-)

Comment: Just wanted to add to this answer that if you configure log4j programmatically (like on https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/customconfig.html) then the solution would be builder.setStatusLevel(Level.OFF);

Answer (score 0):

You should add something similar to your .xml file.

```
<root>
        <priority value="DEBUG"/>
        <appender-ref ref="debug-out"/>
</root>
```

Comment: I am having a similar problem and have a root block like this, but with value="warn". It's not case sensitive or something?

Comment: I have something like this       
<root>
          <priority value ="debug"/>  
          <appender-ref ref="appender"/>
      </root>
But still getting this error